# add multiple attributes to multiple elements in schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I can't figure out how to add attributes for multiple nodes into an xsd file. 
This is my XML File.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:Root xmlns:xs="http://tempuri.org/SchemaFile"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/SchemaFile SchemaFile.xsd"
            xmlns:elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:Node name="attributeName">
    <xs:data name="attributeName" amount="total" />  // These are unbounded.
  </xs:Node>
</xs:Root>
```

Here is what I have so far. I can't get anything to work though.

```
  <sch:element name="Root">
    <sch:complexType>
      <sch:sequence>
        <sch:element name="Node" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <sch:complexType>
            <sch:simpleContent>
              <sch:extension base="sch:string">
                <sch:attribute name="name" type="sch:string"/>
              </sch:extension>
            </sch:simpleContent>
          </sch:complexType>
        </sch:element>
      </sch:sequence>
    </sch:complexType>
  </sch:element>
```

I also tried a global to add the attribute type but i can't get it to work. When i use the type it says i can't have any other complex or simple types along with the attribute declaration for the xmlnode Node.

Comment: Note that `xs` is conventionally used as the namespace prefix for XML Schemas (`http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`) and it's quite confusing when you use that prefix for something else and a different prefix for `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` - I had to read your question twice before I worked out that the instance document was at the top and the schema at the bottom rather than vice-versa...

Comment: The instance document was not the problem. It was a problem in the ordering of the attribute since both my nodes had attributes attached. I thought that attributes would have to be listed first when in fact they have to be listed after the other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that this seems to work. It was the ordering that I messed up on earlier.Root

```
  <sch:element name="Root">
    <sch:complexType>
      <sch:sequence>
        <sch:element name="Node" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <sch:complexType>
            <sch:sequence>
              <sch:element name="Data" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <sch:complexType>
                  <sch:attribute name="name"/>
                  <sch:attribute name="amount"/>
                </sch:complexType>
              </sch:element>
            </sch:sequence>
            <sch:attribute name="name"/>
          </sch:complexType>
        </sch:element>
      </sch:sequence>
    </sch:complexType>
  </sch:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>                    
                    <xs:element name="Node" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="data" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:complexType>                                        
                                        <xs:attribute name="name">
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">                                            
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:attribute>
                                        <xs:attribute name="amount">
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">                                            
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>    
                                        </xs:attribute>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                         </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>                  
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>                      
  </xs:schema>
```

it works for this **XML**  below:

```
<Root>
 <Node>
      <data name="string 1" amount="string 2"/>
      <data name="string 3" amount="string 4"/>
 </Node>    
</Root>
```

Comment: also dont forget to validate this xml file with the above xsd to run properly

Comment: Look at my above question then my post. I have found the solution. This wouldn't help me since it isn't what I asked. Thanks for trying though.